# What does mean that a clock has virtual infinite precision?

Tags: time, clock

In the hwclock man page one can read:

```
(the hardware) clock actually has virtually infinite precision.
```

and also:

```
The System Time is not an integer, though.  It has virtually infinite precision.
```

I don't understand what does virtually stand for in this context. If both hardware and system clocks have infinite precision, why does they have drifting?

(The question is about Linux OS)

Comment: What OS? Please.

Comment: Linux, I'will edit to clarify :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"virtually infinite" means "really high" in this case. (See https://dictionary.reverso.net/english-definition/virtually+infinite )

The OS is spotting the edge, when 1 second of the system clock changes to the next one, so the precision is as good as the time between one query of the clock to the next, which might be one instruction.

Precision isn't the same thing as accuracy. The system clock may be very precise but completely wrong, either in absolute terms, or relative (rate/skew) terms.